# Jquery .val() function not working on global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four radio buttons inside the div and want to store the value of the selected checkbox into a jquery variable. However the code is working fine inside the button scope. However if i declare the variable on the global scope(outside the button scope),the variable returns **undefined**
Here is the jquery code that works fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var x=$('[name=user]:checked').val();
     alert(x);
  });
});
```

Here is the html code associated with it

```
<div class="first-section">
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="one">1</input>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="two">2</input>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="three">3</input>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="four">4</input>
<button class="submit-one">Submit</button>
</div>
```

How to reuse this **x** variable in global scope. On declaring global it returns undefined. Here is the problematic code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x=$('[name=user]:checked').val();
  $('button').click(function(){
     alert(x);
  });
});

//returns Undefined
```

Comment: Your checkbox is not checked when the page loads so `$('[name=user]:checked')` does not return any elements.

Comment: use window.x instead of var x inside document.ready

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't knew that the property set was not dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can declare global value `x` and then change it's value with in your function (in your example in .click() function)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var x
  $('button').click(function(){
     x=$('[name=user]:checked').val();
     alert(x);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked however i still can't find the reason why my previous code didn't worked out

Comment: because you are declaring variable `x` with in scope of `click()` function hence it is not accessible outside of it on global scope

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a variable inside a function, so it will not be accessible outside of the function.

If you want to access `x` outside of the function somewhere else you need to declare it outside of the function e.g.

```js
var x;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     x = $('[name=user]:checked').val();
     alert(x);
  });
});
```